# Gadfly xticks number in Julia histogram

Tags: plot, julia, histogram, gadfly

suppose you have a dataframe with a column called `c_lab` that contains values from 0 to 100 and resembles a log-normal distribution.

I plotted the histogram with this code using gadfly package in Julia:

```
plot(df_plot, x = "c_lab", Geom.histogram(bincount = 100), 
    Guide.title("Pre-Tax Labor Income = h x w"),
    Guide.xlabel("Gross Laboral Income"),
    Guide.ylabel("Frequency"), 
    Theme(background_color = "white"))
```

And produces this plot:

[image]

The thing is in the x-axis I only have 3 values, I want to increment the number of breaks to say 10. (10, 20, 30,..., 100) or 4 (25, 50, 75,100).

In R I'd do it in a ggplot2 code and add `+scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10)`

How can I do the same in Julia Gadfly Package?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It doesn't appear that this feature exists directly in Gadfly, you may have to create something equivalent using `Guide.xticks(ticks = ticks))`

Long answer: I had a look at [the source code for the scales in Gadfly](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/blob/026576ae24065098a76a542a3015dcdc804748d1/src/scale.jl), and though it has minticks and maxticks (so theoretically, if one had access to those, they could set both to the same number to force a certain number of ticks), it's unclear if that is accessible using the function which face the user.

In any case, it's straightforward to do something similar to this by creating an interval from the min to max, with i steps, where i is the number of ticks you want, and min and max are the minimum and maximum values on the x axis.

```
using DataFrames
using Distributions
using Gadfly

# Generate log-normal distributed values
dist = LogNormal(0, 1)
values = quantile.(dist, range(0, stop=1, length=101))

# Create DataFrame
df_plot = DataFrame(c_lab = values)

# using a basic vector
ticks = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Plot the DataFrame using Gadfly
p = plot(df_plot, x = "c_lab", Geom.histogram(bincount = 100),
         Guide.title("Pre-Tax Labor Income = h x w"),
         Guide.xlabel("Gross Laboral Income"),
         Guide.ylabel("Frequency"),
         Theme(background_color = "white"),
         Guide.xticks(ticks = ticks))

# other option: a function 

function tick_vector_creator(df::DataFrame, column::Symbol, num_ticks::Int64)
    # pull the column out into a vector
    column = sort(df[!, column])
    # get the first and last value of column which isn't infinite
    first_value = column[findfirst(column .> -Inf)]
    last_value = column[findlast(column .< Inf)]
    
    interval = (last_value - first_value) ÷ num_ticks
    return range(first_value, stop=last_value, length=num_ticks)
end

# then use this in place of the other ticks variable
ticks = tick_vector_creator(df_plot, :c_lab, 10)
```

[resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUWZv.png)

update: [I asked on the Github page](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/issues/1615), and a maintainer confirmed that the way to do it is with xticks. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for asking and returning with the `tick_vector_creator` function it does really comes in handy!.